# Store text files safely in JAR

Tags: java, jar

Is there any way in Java to store external files (inside jar) safely? Java files are compiled to .class files and not readable.

I'm planning to use this meganism to store sql files, which hold queries, however i dont want those to be readable when one extracts the jar. External files are pre, cause we then have syntax highlighting while developping instead of putting them into a string.

Comment: If that sql files are going to be used by the code that the jar holds, you cannot make it safe. Since the only way is to encrypt them using some key, but the code which reads that sql files should know that key and therefor that key will be accessible using any java debugger.

Comment: FYI - There are decompilers available to read the class file code. see JD-GUI. Just because they are class files doesn't make then unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jar file is pretty much just a .zip file, so you can put whatever you want in them.  There's no built-in encryption, so if you're trying to make the SQL files non-readable, you'll have to encrypt them (and then unencrypt in your code).  I don't understand what you mean by "External files are pre, cause we then have syntax highlighting while developping instead of putting them into a string."

Comment: If you put them inside a class our problem is solved, however we cant easily read them any more since inside a string there is no syntax highlighting and you have to escape any quotes for ex.

Comment: @Ferdy: if putting them inside a class as strings solves your problem (ie you are not fighting against debuggers) you can encrypt sql files (AES, Blowfish) and decrypt when you application starts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, people do this all the time. Just add the files to the jar, and then access them with

[getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). If you build with maven, you just plop them into src/main/resources to get them into the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can put them in the Jar. Once there you can get at them by using the ClassLoader's getResourceAsStream method.

The challenge is to prevent other people extracting them. If your code can read them, so can someone else. What are your requirements here?

Comment: Getting files inside the jar isnt the problem... We want people who extract the jar not being able to read them.

Comment: Have you tried opening a .class file in Notepad? You can read all the String values straight out. You don't even need a debugger.

Comment: @Ferdy "Not being able to read" is impossible.  You can however make it _hard_.   Problem is if it is hard for others it may also be hard for you.